# Value of variable gets overwritten

Tags: c, sdl

Hello I am working on a game written in C with SDL2. I have created a player struct, which has a pointer to an SDL_Rect. But it seems that the value of the rect is being overwritten, which you can see in the screenshot.

[Console of the game, first two logs are the values which it should contain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WU6Q.png)

Here is the Player struct:

```
struct Player* createPlayer(int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Texture* texture) {
  struct Player* player = (struct Player*) malloc(sizeof(struct Player));
  SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, width, height};

  player->rect = &rect;
  player->texture = texture;
  printf("%d\n", player->rect->x);
  return player;
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
struct Player* player = createPlayer(0, 0, 128, 128, texture);
bool running = true;
printf("%d\n", player->rect->x);
while(running) {
  SDL_Event event;

  // UPDATE PLAYERS AND STUFF HERE

  while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch(event.type) {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        running = false;

        break;
    }
  }

  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

  // RENDER PLAYERS AND STUFF HERE
  printf("%d\n", player->rect->x); <- This is where the different values come from
  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, player->texture, NULL, player->rect);

  //

  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: You're using the address of a local variable with  `player->rect = &rect;`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you! I solved it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the pointer to a local variable:

```
  SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, width, height};

  player->rect = &rect;
```

The local variable will be invalid once it goes out of scope (when reaching the end of the function), and any pointer to it will point to invalid memory -> undefined behaviour.

Write ...

```
  SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, width, height};

  player->rect = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect);
  *player->rect = rect;
```